# Chunking a django-import-export

Tags: django, django-import-export, chunking

I am reading this [article](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2019/01/09/django-bulk-inserts/) about chunking a large database operation. I am also using `django-import-export` and `django-import-export-celery` in my admin site and I would like to integrate chunking into them.

The problem I have is `django-import-export` already handles the file import, as well as the whole process of importing, in the background.

I tried using `django-import-export`'s [bulk imports](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bulk_import.html), but one of the caveats is:

> Bulk operations do not work with many-to-many relationships.

so chunking is what we thought was the alternative. Is it possible to perform chunking inside the `django-import-export`?

**UPDATE - ADDED MODEL**:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    associated_issuer = models.ManyToManyField('app.Issuer', related_name='add_issuer', blank=True)
    associated_profile = models.ManyToManyField('app.Profile', related_name='add_profile', blank=True)

class Issuer(models.Model):
    # personal information
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    contact_email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    associated_profile = models.ManyToManyField('app.Profile', related_name='add_profile_2', blank=True)
    associated_issuer = models.ManyToManyField('app.Issuer', related_name='add_issuer_2', blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you share your models? Just to confirm, you are not able to use bulk imports because of many to many fields? Because otherwise you can tell `django-import-export` to use `bulk_create` by using [use_bulk](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.ResourceOptions.use_bulk) and chunk/batch it by using [batch_size](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.ResourceOptions.batch_size)

Comment: @BrianDestura added the model with the manytomanyfield